# Средства для подсчета тестового покрытия

Tags: c, code-coverage, метрики, тестирование, c++

Какие есть бесплатные инструменты для подсчета тестового покрытия кода, написанного на C или C++?

Answer (score 1):

- [COVTOOL](http://covtool.sourceforge.net/): Бесплатный анализатор тестового покрытия для C++.
- [GCOV](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html): Инструмент, используемый совместно с GCC, для подсчета тестового покрытия.

Дополнительные источники:

- [Is there any free C++ code coverage tool which is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84109/is-there-any-free-c-code-coverage-tool-which-is-useful)?
- [10 Code Coverage Tools for C & C++](http://open-tube.com/10-code-coverage-tools-c-c)